Facing Problem with npx run:android where my tabs header are showing where I set them false everywhere
When I am using this to run my app: npx expo run:android it's build my app & run on my emulator. Everything works fine but one problem is my headers are showing while I add headerShown false both in rootlayout file & tabs layout file. The followings are given below:
RootLayout:
if (user) {
    return (
      <Stack
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)"/>
        <Stack.Screen name="ChatRoom"
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            headerTitle: '',

          }} />
      </Stack>
    );

Tablayout:
export default function TabLayout() {

    return (
        <Tabs screenOptions={{ 
            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'orange',
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            tabBarShowLabel: true,
            headerShown: false,

but it is still showing. Is there any other way to solve this? Only Tabs are creating problems. In 'npx expo start' everything works fine but I can't use firebase native modules that that's why I am using this facing this problem. You can see the image for better understanding
I tried giving all the layouts screenoptions headershown False but still not working

you have to make headerShown: false In Stack.Navigator's screenOptions.
You can refer the code snippet from below.
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Splash"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

